# Change folder permissions on remote pc

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file with a lot of pc names inside. I need to change folder permissions of a specific folder on each pc for thr local group "users" -> read and write. the folder is always the same.

I've got the following. if i only put one computername in the txt file it works well but if i put two or more, it doens't work.

this is what i have

```
$file = get-content -path "C:\pcnames.txt"

$acl = get-acl -path "$file\C$\testfolder1" 
$new = "users","write, read","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow" 
$accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new 
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) 
$acl | Set-Acl "$file\C$\testfolder1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `Get-Content` will return an array if there are multiple lines. You therefor need to loop through every element in the `$file` array.

Your code will look something like this:

```
$file = get-content -path "C:\pcnames.txt"

foreach($pc in $file) {
    $acl = get-acl -path "$pc\C$\testfolder1" 
    $new = "users","write, read","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow" 
    $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new 
    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) 
    $acl | Set-Acl "$pc\C$\testfolder1"
}
```